# How does the control flow between two modules when both are importing the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python.I am trying to understand how control flows between imported modules. I don't understand why the code is giving an error. I am not trying to acheive anything, i just want an explanation for the error

---

**mod1.py**

```
import pckg1.mod2  

print("In mod 1 : My name : ",\_\_name\_\_)    
print("In mod 2 : imported package name :",pckg1.mod2.\_\_name\_\_)
```

**mod2.py**

```
import pckg1.mod1  

print("In mod 2: My name ",\_\_name\_\_)  
print("In mod2 : imported package name",pckg1.mod1.\_\_name\_\_)
```

---

**Error message :**

> print("In mod2 : imported package name",pckg1.mod1.__name__)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mod1'

**Output:**

> In mod 2: My name  pckg1.mod2

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that behavior in the debugger. If you debug `mod2.py`, you will see that it immediately steps into `mod1.py`, caused by the import statement. Once inside `mod1.py`, there is another import statement, where the execution returns to `mod2.py`
As can be seen in the [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20modules#sys.modules) dictionary, at this point only `pckg1` is available, but not it's child `mod2`.

In `mod2.py` the import statement does not cause `mod1.py` to be executed again (see [Python Circular Imports](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) and [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem)) for further information), and execution continues with the print statements.

So in your example, `mod1` is not completely loaded, caused by the circular reference, and thus not available.